# adding items into list by for loops

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, charts, silverlight-3.0

I am creating a chart for windows phone 7.

This is the foreach for each hawker returned:

```
void dbSvc_retrievepopularhawkerCompleted(object sender, RouteServiceRef.retrievepopularhawkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    List<RouteServiceRef.Hawker> recommendPlaceList;
    recommendPlaceList = e.Result.Cast<RouteServiceRef.Hawker>().ToList();

    string hawkername = "";
    string address = "";
    string postal = "";
    double coordX = 0.0;
    double coordY = 0.0;
    double popularity = 0;



    foreach (RouteServiceRef.Hawker rp in recommendPlaceList)
    {
        hawkername = rp.hawkername;
        address = rp.address;
        postal = rp.postal;
        coordX = rp.xcoord;
        coordY = rp.ycoord;
        popularity = rp.popularity;


    }
```

I have to change the above codes to be inside this list of cities:

```
 List<City> cities = new List<City> { new City { Name = "CLE", Population = 2250871 }, new City { Name = "CMH", Population = 1773120 }, new City { Name = "CVG", Population = 2155137 }, new City { Name = "DET", Population = 4425110 } };
```

such as: `List<City> cities = new List<City> { new City Name = hawkername, Population = popularity }`

so that I can do a bind to my chart:

```
 ColumnSeries bs = ChartControl.Series[0] as ColumnSeries; bs.ItemsSource = cities;
```

I am not sure how to mix them up, can someone guide me along ? As I do not want to hard code the name and population inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's easy, Just follow the code below.

Declare the list of City Above the foreach loop and on each iteration just add new item to the list

```
List<City> cities = new List<City> ();

foreach (RouteServiceRef.Hawker rp in recommendPlaceList)
    {
        hawkername = rp.hawkername;
        address = rp.address;
        postal = rp.postal;
        coordX = rp.xcoord;
        coordY = rp.ycoord;
        popularity = rp.popularity;
        cities.Add(new City(){Name = hawkername, Population = popularity });
    }
```

This fills the cities list as well on the completion of foreach loop.